# Groups - Profile cannot be added?

Tags: profile

Is it possible to create a Public/Private Group, grouping few Profiles? I do not find an option to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ItamAAC) which was closed down stating that such solutions are available on AppExchange.  One such tool is [GroupMaster](https://full-sites.cs12.force.com/appexchange/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Jj1aEAC&revId=a0S3000000Hc44rEAB&tab=r) which can group profiles.